# How to load kernel modules in C/C++ program

Tags: python, c++, c, raspberry-pi, kernel-module

I am working with the ds18b20 temperature sensor and I am working on converting some python code to c++ to help learn the language better. I have run across a problem where I need to load the w1-gpio and w1-therm modules. I have found quite a few things on stack overflow mentioning that init_module should be used, and in the same thread someone else mentions to use `fork()` along side `exec()`. After much googling and reading through the man pages, I can't find any examples of how to accomplish either of these tasks. Could someone point me to and/or give an example of how I would load these two modules with either of these methods? Or provide an alternative that does not involve system("modprobe w1-gpio")?

```
uname -a
```

produces:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The simplest solution is definitely `system("modprobe w1-gpio")` or something similar.

Comment: Check the sourcecode of `modprobe` to find out how it does it and (completely unnecessarily) replicate the functionality in your program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still hold that `system("modprobe ...")` is a perfectly good solution for this situation. It is just causing yourself extra issues to NOT do that.

If you know exactly which kernel modules you want to load, then using [`init_module`](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?2%20init_module) or it's sibling `finit_module`. But you will need to load modules in the right order. And of course, need to know all the relevant places where files are kept, what argument(s) they need, etc.

And don't forget to reverse the order for `delete_module` when you are cleaning up after yourself.

The source of `modprobe` and friends can be found here:
https://github.com/vadmium/module-init-tools

insmod is quite short, but modproble is a little over 2300 lines of code.

Comment: Prefer `/sbin/modprobe` as opposed to calling `modprobe` directly. This protects you against attacks where someone places a binary called `modprobe` that does evil things as root, and then calls the real `modprobe`